# Assign a different type based on a ternary statement in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
selection: (InterfaceX | InterfaceY)[]

interface InterfaceX {
  switch: boolean
  propertyOne: number
}

interface InterfaceY {
  switch: boolean
  propertyTwo: number
}
```

Selection can be:

```
{switch: true, propertyOne: 1} or {switch: false, propertyTwo: 2}
```

Which causes the following type errors in a ternary:

```
selection.switch ? selection.propertyOne : selection.propertyTwo

TS2339: Property 'propertyOne' does not exist on type 'InterfaceY'.
```

As well as

```
TS2339: Property 'propertyTwo' does not exist on type 'InterfaceX'.
```

Is there a way to declare which side of the ternary is using which type? So if switch is true it is `InterfaceX` otherwise its `InterfaceY`? I do not want to add any properties to my interfaces. Thanks!

**New example:**

```
import React from "react";

export interface Props {
  items: (InterfaceX | InterfaceY)[];
}

interface InterfaceX {
  toggle: true;
  sharedProp: string;
  propertyX: string;
}

interface InterfaceY {
  toggle: false;
  sharedProp: string;
  propertyY: string;
}

export const Picks = (props: Props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  return items.map(item =>
    item.toggle ? (
      <div>
        {item.sharedProp} {item.propertyX} // Unresolved variable propertyX
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {item.sharedProp} {item.propertyY} // Unresolved variable propertyY
      </div>
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: How are you defining your interfaces? This appears to be working (assuming you define your interfaces this way): http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJANZBvAKGWQGcB3YMBACwC5kwoBXCAbiOQAcoB7T6MAE8A8iAj0QTALYAjaOwC+BAqEixEKdGqwQAmvg7lKNevAA2JNh258BggCpkeE6XKiLlCHiBJhkMEABGZABeZAAKSzMIBDBgb3otTA1cAB80DHUkXQBKUIA+A2IomLjvADojKmpkAH5SCGjY+JBym34oIVEUehLmiva7Rx4CJQIvHz8AgCZQiL6ykETMnTSM7Q1cgqLSCmr5xtKWyr2aPMJiYgQ4SwZmcQ5L5CgIMCYoEAamxbbeDq6xOwntdbuZLLRHpcXm8Pl8jgM-kMnBwlAogA

Comment: @skovy you have true false instead of boolean in there

Comment: Hmm, yea based off your example of what the `selection` can be it's either `true` for `InterfaceX` or true for `InterfaceY` -- without this, how would TypeScript be able to discriminate between the two?

Comment: ah maybe I was thinking about it wrong, if true is a valid type

Comment: that will work actually, I'd always assumed that it had to be boolean for some reason - post it down below and I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example you'll want the `switch` property to be the exact value (not `boolean`) so that TypeScript can properly [discriminate between the two types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html). Otherwise, since they can both be `false` and `true` there's no way to determine which type it is.

For example:

```js
interface InterfaceX {
  switch: true;
  propertyOne: number;
}

interface InterfaceY {
  switch: false;
  propertyTwo: number;
}

// Example of using a ternary
const fn1 = (selection: InterfaceX | InterfaceY) => {
  selection.switch ? selection.propertyOne : selection.propertyTwo
}

// Example of using a swtich
const fn2 = (selection: InterfaceX | InterfaceY) => {
  switch (selection.switch) {
    case true:
      return selection.propertyOne;
    case false:
      return selection.propertyTwo
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJANZBvAKGWQGcB3YMBACwC5kwoBXCAbiOQAcoB7T6MAE8A8iAj0QTALYAjaOwC+BAqEixEKdGqwQAmvg7lKNevAA2JNh258BggCpkeE6XKiLlAek-IAogA84KU4zFB4YZCYSUABzZDgGaBA4KEECBB4QEjBkGBAARmQAXmQACktQhDBgTPotTA1cAB80DHUkXQBKYoA+A2IKiCqakAA6IypqZAB+UghK6szRm34oIVEUekHhpZW7Rx4CJQJvP0Dg0ORwyOiQOITyapp0zOzckAAmYrLtxZA6to6ZqtbQaLq9fqkCiTH7zIZ-cbQmjdQjEYgIOCWBjMcQcNHIKAQMBMKAgOYLEbLXirdZidj4jFY8yWWh4tGE4mk8nwyl7NYOJwcJQKIA)

Comment: Ah damn do we have to use a switch here? I'm writing some JSX. Would be returning something like `switch ? <a>{s.propertyOne}</a> : <a>{s.propertyTwo}</a>`. I tried and still get a type error with the ternary.

Comment: You should be able to use a ternary or a switch. I included both when I was originally testing. The ternary should be above the switch example

Comment: I have updated my example as this doesnt work for me unfortunately

Comment: Ah I got it, you have to add (item as InterfaceX), then this works. Thank you!